# single 2008 R2 Domain controller cannot find itself

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-dns

I have a 2008 R2 Standard server that acts as Domain controller and has exchange 2010 installed. There are no other servers in the environment.

I'm having some problems with the exchange services starting and, on investigation, can see that it is because the server seems unable to find itself as a domain controller.

I've ensured that the NIC has its DNS set to the internal IP of the server.
I've also checked that DNS services are started, and indeed they are.

I've run DCDIAG and here are the results...

[image]

I was thinking this feels like a DNS issue, and sure enough, right there in the event log...

[image]

NSLookup is giving the following...

[image]

The error given on exchange services is...

```
 The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost did not return any suitable domain controllers.
```

not sure where to go from here.

Anyone encountered this before?

Comment: 1. What is the server using for DNS in the NIC properties? 2. Have you followed the event log suggestion?

Comment: primary DNS is 10.50.55.24 and secondary is 127.0.0.1.
I have amended anything in the registry yet, but I did just notice a weird response from nslookup... I'll update above

Answer (score 1):

I checked the hosts file and found a hardcoded incorrect address for localhost.
*sigh*

Removed the entry and all is well again!